# How to set tiny font in axis labels with pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, labels

i am doing a plot with pgfplots with data from a file. It takes the values from the file correctly but when i compile the pdf it prints the label with the same dimension of the text with which i'm writing my report. I want it smaller.
My code for the plot's setup in the preamble is like this:

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{every tick label/.append style={font=\tiny},label style=
 {font=\tiny},width=6.5cm,height=5.5cm,compat=1.3}
```

while in the document i have:

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\subfloat[Andamento nel tempo di pressione e temperatura]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=0, xmax=90,axis y line*=left,ymin=8.62,ymax=8.69, xlabel=
{Tempo (ore)}, ylabel={Pressione (bar)}]
\addplot[thick,black] table[x=tempo,y=P_mean] 
{capitolo4/grafici/t_meanVSp_mean2.txt};
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[xmin=0, xmax=90,axis y line*=right,ymin=20.5,ymax=23.0, 
ylabel=Temperatura (°C)]
\addplot[dashed,black] table[x=tempo,y=T_mean]
{capitolo4/grafici/t_meanVSp_mean2.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\subfloat[Confronto tra la pressione misurata sperimentalmente e la   
 pressione calcolata con il modello di gas perfetto]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=0, xmax=90,ymin=8.55,ymax=8.75,xlabel=Tempo (ore), 
ylabel=Pressione (bar)]
\addplot[only marks,mark=o] table[x=tempo,y=p_sp]
{capitolo4/grafici/t_meanVSp_mean3.txt};
\addplot[thick,black] table[x=tempo,y=p_id]
{capitolo4/grafici/t_meanVSp_mean3.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{figure}
```

I attach also the plots that i get with this code. 
Hope i've been sufficently clear!
thank you bye

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `compat` option before `label style`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
  compat=1.3,
  tick label style={font=\tiny},
  label style={font=\tiny},
  width=6.5cm,
  height=5.5cm}
\begin{document}
Normal text
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=0, xmax=90,axis y line*=left,ymin=8.62,ymax=8.69, xlabel=
{Tempo (ore)}, ylabel={Pressione (bar)}]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: now i'am trying to add a legend for the two plots but i can't succeed. I add 'legend style={at={(1,1)},anchor=south east}' and than '\legend={}' but it doesn't show the name in the legend, only the marks.

Comment: Maybe it is better to ask a new question with a minimal working example. Note that we can not use your code in this question because we do not have your files.